# Object doesn't support property or method 'someMethod'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, hoisting, window-object

I am getting this error in IE 11 on Windows 10 `TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'someMethod'`. I am using React and calling a method named `someMethod` inside `componentDidMount` in `Full.js` file.

The `someMethod` method is defined outside `src` directory of react using jQuery externally (and not inside react like this `import $ from jquery`) using `<script>` tag in `index.html`. And I am accessing that method in my `Full.js` as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.someMethod();
}
```

And that's the place I am getting the error in IE 11 and the above code is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and even in Edge but not in IE 11.
I tried hitting `window` in the console of IE but I couldn't find `someMethod` but it is showing in Firefox's and Chrome's console.

The `someMethod` method is defined inside a file named `methods.js` in `code` directory outside of `src` directory and I am getting the same error when calling other methods defined in this file in the following manner:

```
function someMethod() {
    // Some code here
}
```

Is this is a problem with IE regarding [Javascript Hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)?

**PS:** I have `core-js` polyfill installed in my project and I also tried declaring the `someMethod` method I the following manner as well but still no luck:

```
var someMethod = function() {
    // Some Code here
}
```

Comment: Is the function *really* called "someMethod" or is there another name? IE protects many global symbols.

Comment: The name is different I just used someMethod for demo purpose.

Comment: OK, well what is the real name of the function? The name itself could explain the problem. Have you tried changing the name to literally "someMethod" to see if that affects things?

Comment: It has anything to do with the name of the function. I tried changing the name of the function but still got the same error with the newly changed function name.